# Is a continuous functor the generalization of a continuous function?

Tags: category-theory

See title, and if so, what is the intuition? If not, how does category theory generalize continuous functions?

Comment: Your second question seems rather strange--why should category theory generalize continuous functions?

Comment: Good question Eric. I'm not sure. I think I was just confused.